# I installed Oracle Java JDK 8 but java command line is still reporting it is version 7

Tags: macos, java

I installed jdk 1.8.0 u5, but the command line java is reporting 1.7:

```
$ java -fullversion
java full version "1.7.0_51-b13"

$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Oct 23  2013 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Here is what is installed

```
$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
total 64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 23  2013 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 23  2013 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 23  2013 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 23  2013 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 23  2013 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 23  2013 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272 May 13 10:21 A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1 Oct 23  2013 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   59 Oct 23  2013 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

also:

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java -fullversion
java full version "1.7.0_51-b13"
```

The java control panel applet reports 1.8, but in /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/

Any idea where it went?

Comment: How exactly did you install the JDK - Oracle has made it confusion

Comment: The link to install the JDK in the comment below at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192180/145778 resolves this issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Java 7 and Java 8 are installed under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, and to get informations about the installed Java VM's you can use the [/usr/libexec/java_home](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/java_home.1.html) command, which is a link/shortcut to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home`.

Some of the command to use are:

`/usr/libexec/java_home -verbose` will give you all installed versions with path.

`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.6*'` will give you JAVA_HOME of Java 6

`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'` will give you JAVA_HOME of Java 7 (if installed)

`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.8*'` will give you JAVA_HOME of Java 8 (if installed)

And if `/usr/libexec/java_home` is called without any parameters you should get the current enabled (newest) Java version. If you don't get the newest Java version when `/usr/libexec/java_home` is called, you can try a restart of your Mac, so that the system reload its current load of the `/usr/bin/java` link/shortcut to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem on OS X Yosemite 10.9.

The problem was solved by installing the [Java SE Development Kit 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

I had installed the other version that is not a SE development kit and it was just working in web browsers, not for the terminal.

Comment: I installed the JDK, as you suggested, and everything works now. Many thanks!!

Comment: Worked for me! been trying to find jdk8 and finally this fixed my issue. thanks

Comment: I needed to do this, but still had problems because my .bash_profile had JAVA_HOME pointing to /Library/Java/Home, where 1.6 was installed.